# Sorting a doubly linked list in C

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I'm trying to create a program that reads a text file
from standard input and prints the words and their frequency sorted by decreasing frequency. To do this I store the words in a linked list, and if the linked list already contains a word, its frequency is updated. I haven't been able to sort the linked list by the frequency of the words however.

The `struct` I'm using looks like this:

```
struct list {
    char *word;
    struct list *previous;
    struct list *next;
    int count;
};
```

So I understand I should compare the `count` value of each node with that of its neighbour and then switch their position if depending on the `count` value, however I don't know how I can keep a function looping until it's sorted.

What part of my code looks like:

```
struct list {
    char *word;
    struct list *previous;
    struct list *next;
    int count;
};

void list_add(struct list *l, char *word) {
    struct list *current = l->previous;
    struct list *prev;
    int already_in_list = 0;
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->word, word) == 0) {
            current->count++;
            already_in_list = 1;
            // Compare new frequency with elements higher 
            // up in the list and sort*/ 
            **How do I do this?**
        }
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    if (already_in_list != 1) list_add_new(l, word);
}
```

Current output is:

```
word: bye   count: 1
word: is    count: 1
word: my    count: 1
word: hello count: 6
word: world count: 2
word: name  count: 1
```

What I want as output:

```
word: hello count: 6
word: world count: 2
word: name  count: 1
word: bye   count: 1
word: is    count: 1
word: my    count: 1
```

Comment: With your expected output: should there be any ordering of words of equal occurence? There doesn't seem to be right now...

Comment: No, why should there be?

Comment: I was asking whether the words of equal occurence should be ordered in some way, and, if so, how you would order them; either alphabetically, unmodified, random placement, etc.

Comment: I don't really care in what way words with equal frequency are ordered.

Comment: The best way to sort a linked list: 1) create an array of pointers to the elements of the linked list, 2) sort the pointers using the `qsort` library function, 3) recreate the linked list from the sorted array of pointers.

Comment: Please put the code in the question itself and not as a link to an external site. External links may go away making your question useless for future readers. "I don't know how I can keep a function looping until it's sorted". You are only adding one element at a time to a sorted list. So at the point of the add, the element either is new in which case it goes at the end.  Or it is an existing element in which case the count increments and it either stays where it is or you keep moving it backward until it is in the right spot.

Comment: @Mosbas You may not  have characterised the problem properly (at least in the question title). It is not really "how to sort a list". It is really "how to insert or update an element into a sorted list". Because the code only has an "add" operation and no "sort" operation. Please clarify that point as well.

Comment: @kaylum The code doesn't have a `sort` function yet, because I don't know how to implement it; that's why I posted here. It isn't really a "how to insert or update an element into a sorted list", that's what you have made of it. To be honest, sorting it while updating the frequency seems like a good idea, but I still don't know how I would do that.

Comment: My apologies for misunderstanding. Didn't realise you haven't attempted the sort code at all. In that case you need to first decide on what sorting algorithm you want to use and also let us know whether you need to write the sort code yourself from scratch or whether you are allowed to use library functions such as `qsort` as suggested by the other comment.

Comment: @kaylum I'm sure I'm allowed to use qsort, but I wouldn't know how. Your suggestion of sorting when updating the frequency sounds good as well, but while trying to implement it I keep getting segmentation faults.

Comment: About the question about ASCII... Perhaps this piece of code I wrote will show you what is exactly your problem: https://ideone.com/9qOB9S

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by distributing your list into *buckets*.  If you have an array large enough to hold the biggest word count, then you can reorder the list in (almost) linear time:

Create an array of `list` pointers and initialise them all to NULL.  Call this the "frequency lists".  All you do is unlink each node in your main list and put it into its appropriate frequency list (indexed by word count).  If you traverse the main list in reverse, and insert at the front of the frequency list, no extra traversals are required and natural word ordering is maintained.

Once your main list is empty, traverse the frequency list array (in reverse) and concatenate them all.  Now you have sorted your list by word count only.

The only problem is it's not *quite* linear time because the distribution of frequency counts could potentially be quite wide.  You could use some other structure (e.g. hashing) to look up a frequency table more efficiently.  For most practial purposes, it would still be *mostly* linear, and definitely better than logarithmic.

*Caveat:* I don't know why I made such a fuss about linear time, because your code is essentially **O(N^2)** because adding each word to your main list involves searching the entire list to see if it's already in there.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is actually a bit less trivial than sorting if you always keep the list sorted:

You need to traverse the linked list in order to find whether the word you are looking for is already there. In case you find it, increment its count, unlink the node from the list and link it back in where the proper count is. (Note in this case you do not need to traverse the whole list to find the proper insert position - You already know the node needs to move backwards in the list)

In case the word is not known, create a new node (make sure you allocate memory for the string pointer in the node!) and link that to the beginning of the list.

Note the code is not a full implementation. Just some snippets to search for the nodes based on word and word count (the former is needed to find out if we already have that word, the latter is used when you move a node backwards because you have incremented a word count)

```
struct list * findNode (char * word){
    struct list * tmp = root;

    do {
        if (strcmp (word, tmp->word) == 0) {
          return tmp;
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
    } while (tmp != NULL)
    return NULL;
}

/* Finds the first node with a greater word count after start */
struct list * findCount (struct list * start, int count) {
    struct list * tmp = start;

    do {
        if (tmp->count > count) {
          /* return the last node that was smaller than count */
          return tmp->previous;
        }

        if (tmp->next = NULL)
            return tmp;

        tmp = tmp->next;
    } while (tmp != NULL)
    return NULL;
}

void moveAfter (struct list * from, struct list * to) {
    if (from == to)
        return;

    /* Unlink from where we are */
    if (from->previous != NULL) 
       from->previous->next = from->next;
    else
       root = from->next;
    /* from->next can't be NULL, otherwise we wouldn't move */
    from->next->previous = from->previous;

    /* link into new place */
    if (to->next != NULL)
       to->next->previous = from;
    from->next = to->next;
    to->next = from;
    from->previous = to;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your insertion code to keep the list sorted by decreasing frequency.

I modified your code to make the list stub `next` pointer point to the beginning of the list while its `previous` member points to the last element of the list.  The first list element's `previous` pointer points to the list stub and the last element's `next` pointer is `NULL`.

Here is the modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//#include "analyser_ll.h"

struct list {
    char *word;
    struct list *previous;
    struct list *next;
    int count;
};

typedef struct list list;

struct list *list_init(void);
void list_print(struct list *l);
void list_add(struct list *list, const char *word);
int list_cleanup(struct list *l);

list *list_init(void) {
    list *l = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    l->word = NULL;
    l->previous = NULL;
    l->next = NULL;
    l->count = 1;
    return l;
}

/* list ordering function:
 - NULL word is less to keep list stub at the beginning
 - higher count is smaller
 - lexicographic order of word for same count
 */
int list_compare(list *a, list *b) {
    if (a->word == NULL) return -1;
    if (b->word == NULL) return 1;
    if (a->count > b->count) return -1;
    if (a->count < b->count) return 1;
    return strcmp(a->word, b->word);
}

void list_add(list *l, const char *word) {
    list *current = l->next;
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->word, word) == 0) {
            current->count++;
            break;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    if (current == NULL) {
        /* insert new node at end */
        current = list_init();
        current->word = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
        strcpy(current->word, word);

        if (l->next == NULL) {
            l->next = current;
            current->previous = l;
        } else {
            current->previous = l->previous;
            l->previous->next = current;
        }
        l->previous = current;
    }
    /* move current node to the proper position */
    while (list_compare(current->previous, current) > 0) {
        /* swap current and previous nodes */
        list *prev = current->previous;
        list *next = current->next;
        current->previous = prev->previous;
        current->next = prev;
        current->previous->next = current;
        prev->previous = current;
        prev->next = next;
        if (next) {
            next->previous = prev;
        } else {
            l->previous = prev;
        }
    }
}

void list_print(list *l) {
    list *current = l->next;

    // List is empty.
    if (current == NULL) printf("List is empty!\n");

    // While the linked list isn't empty, print
    // the word in every node.
    while (current != NULL && current->word != NULL && current->count > 0) {
        printf("word: %s\tcount: %d\n", current->word, current->count);
        current = current->next;
    } 
}

int list_cleanup(struct list *l) {
    list *current = l->next;

    // Free all list nodes and their contents
    while (current != NULL) {
        struct list *next = current->next;
        free(current->word);
        free(current);
        current = next;
    }

    // Free head of linked list and return.
    free(l);
    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    list *test = list_init();
    list_add(test, "name");
    list_add(test, "world");
    list_add(test, "hello");
    list_add(test, "world");
    list_add(test, "my");
    list_add(test, "hello");
    list_add(test, "is");
    list_add(test, "bye");
    list_add(test, "hello");
    list_add(test, "hello");
    list_add(test, "hello");
    list_add(test, "hello");    
    list_print(test);
    list_cleanup(test);
}
```

Comment: When running this code the output becomes just: word: bye count: 1. Changing my printing function so that it does work, it doesn't seem to update the frequency properly anymore as well.

Comment: @Mosbas: The was an inconsistency in the list handlng functions: the list stub's `next` member should point to the first list node and the `previous` member should point to the last element.  I updated the answer with the modified code.